# How do you use columnconfigure with a scrollable frame in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a scrollable frame where a grid manages the widgets inside of it with different weights. However, `columnconfigure` doesn't seem to be impacting the widgets within the scrollable frame. In this code snippet, I'm using Pmw.ScrollableFrame, but I've also tried `tkscrolledframe` and the code outline here: https://blog.teclado.com/tkinter-scrollable-frames/, but they all seem to be having the same issue.

```
from Pmw import ScrolledFrame

root = Tk()
root.state("zoomed")

Grid.columnconfigure(root, 0, weight = 4)
Grid.columnconfigure(root, 1, weight = 5)

Grid.rowconfigure(root, 0, weight = 1)
Grid.rowconfigure(root, 1, weight = 15)
Grid.rowconfigure(root, 2, weight = 3)

sf = ScrolledFrame(root)

Grid.columnconfigure(sf.interior(), index = 0, weight = 1)
Grid.columnconfigure(sf.interior(), index = 1, weight = 100)

for i in range(100):
    Button(sf.interior(), text = "button 1").grid(row = i, column = 0, sticky = 'nsew')
    Button(sf.interior(), text = "button 2").grid(row = i, column = 1, sticky = 'nsew')
    
sf.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = 'nsew')

Button(root, text = "button 2").grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = 'nsew')
Button(root, text = "button 3").grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = 'nsew', columnspan = 2)
Button(root, text = "button 4").grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = 'nsew')

root.mainloop()
```

If I simply can't user columnconfigure on these types of frames, what else can I use to control the size of widgets inside a scrollable frame without hard-coding the size? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit to add: I intend to populate the scrollable frame with a combination of entry boxes, check boxes, and option menus.

Comment: I’m not familiar with the pms widgets, but there aren’t any limitations with columnconfigure. Can you explain more about why you think it isn’t working?

Comment: @BryanOakley When I execute the code in the question, the buttons are appearing as the same size in the scrollable frame despite the column weights of columns 0 and 1 being 1 and 100 respectively. This is the case if I replace the buttons with entry widgets instead as well.

Comment: This sounds like it's working as designed. Adding weights doesn't cause the window to grow or shrink, it just tells grid how to allocate extra space. If you don't have any extra, unused space, that's when column weights are used.

Comment: @BryanOakley It's not the window I want to change size, it's the widgets within the ScrolledFrame. When I place the buttons on a Frame, they are different sizes from each other dependent on the different column weights, but when I place them in the ScrolledFrame, they are the same size.

Comment: I don't understand the question. In your examples, the buttons are all the same size because... the buttons are all the same size. You tell them to stick to the edges so naturally they are going to be the same size as the column they are in.

Comment: The way PMW is defined, the inner frame is only going to be as wide as the widgets inside it. Is the real question how to get that inner frame to fill the entire widget?

Comment: @BryanOakley Ah, I didn't realize the Frame wasn't already filling the widget. I suppose that would be the question then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't with `columnconfigure`. The problem is that the inner frame isn't expanding to fill the window.

The Pmw.ScrolledFrame class has a [documented attribute](http://pmw.sourceforge.net/doc/ScrolledFrame.html) `horizflex` which can be set to `expand` to have it fill the window.

> **horizflex**
> Specifies how the width of the scrollable interior frame should be resized relative to the clipping frame. If '**fixed**', the interior frame is set to the natural width, as requested by the child widgets of the frame. If '**expand**' and the requested width of the interior frame is less than the width of the clipping frame, the interior frame expands to fill the clipping frame. If '**shrink**' and the requested width of the interior frame is more than the width of the clipping frame, the interior frame shrinks to the width of the clipping frame. If '**elastic**', the width of the interior frame is always set to the width of the clipping frame. The default is '**fixed**'.

It sounds like you should set it to `expand`

```
sf = ScrolledFrame(root, horizflex="expand")
```

Comment: Yep, that does it. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the builtin function of scrolltext with a `Textbox` or a `Frame` just by changing the values. If you want to put something else you might want to use `insert`, `delete`, and `StringVariable()`.

```py
import tkinter

root = Tk()
scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
textbox = Text(root)
textbox.pack()
for i in range(100):
    textbox.insert(END, f"Scrolling Text Label {i}\n")
textbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=textbox.yview)
root.mainloop()
```

Edit: If you want detection on the scrollbar, because you are using `PMW` you can use the `binding` system which represents `scrolled` for this occasion.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I should have mentioned this in the question and will edit to add, but I intend to eventually populate the scrollable frame with a combination of entry boxes, check boxes, and option menus, so a textbox doesn't quite work for this.